# Inverse Trigonometric functions - Boyce & Diprima 2.2.19

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem asks for a solution to the initial value problem:

\begin{align}
&\sin(2x)dx+\cos(3y)dy=0\\
&y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align}

The problem is separable and I arrive at the following implicit solution:

\begin{align}
\sin(3y)-3\cos^2(x)=0
\end{align}

If I now take an $\arcsin$ of both sides and solve for $y$ I would naively have:

\begin{align}
y(x)=\frac{1}{3}\arcsin\left(3\cos^2(x)\right)
\end{align}

However, when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have LHS $=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and RHS $=0 $ which seems to be a problem. The solution provided in the book shifts the RHS by $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Could someone explain what is really going on here? thx

The author's given solution is:

\begin{align}
y(x)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\pi-\arcsin\left(3\cos^2(x)\right)\right)
\end{align}

Comment: After integrate $RHS=constant$!

Comment: Am I completely missing something??  Surely the general solution of the DE is$$\frac{\sin2x}{2}-\frac{\cos3y}{3}=C\ ,$$and the initial condition gives $C=1/3$.

Comment: I wrote down the original prob. with cos and sin switched. It is correct now. thx

Comment: OK, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your equation gives
$$\sin3y=3\cos^2x$$
and hence
$$3y=\arcsin(3\cos^2x)+2k\pi\quad\hbox{or}\quad 3y=-\arcsin(3\cos^2x)+(2k+1)\pi$$
for some integer $k$.  Checking the initial condition, these give respectively
$$\pi=2k\pi\quad\hbox{or}\quad\pi=(2k+1)\pi\ .$$
The first is impossible, the second gives $k=0$ and hence
$$3y=-\arcsin(3\cos^2x)+\pi\ .$$

Comment: this is equivalent to mine. the question is not about this though.

Comment: Fair enough, see altered answer.

Comment: The second line is a general result for $arcsin(~)$? even and odd separation like this?

Comment: Yes, general solution of $\sin x=\sin\alpha$ is $x=\alpha+2k\pi$ or $x=(\pi-\alpha)+2k\pi$.  To see why, draw on the same axes the graphs of $y=\sin x$ and $y=\sin\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ is a constant).

Comment: I will read about this again. thx David

Answer (score 0):

After integrating you have:

> $$ - \frac{1}{2} \cos{2x} + \frac{1}{3} \sin{3y} = K, \quad K \in \mathbb{R}, $$

which is as nice as an explicit solution. Substitute the initial data to find the value of the constant of integration:

> $$ - \frac{1}{2} \cos{\pi} + \frac{1}{3} \sin{\pi} = \frac{1}{2} = K, $$

and you are done. I don't think finding an explicit solution for $y(x)$ before is a good idea.

Cheers!